# How to install gcc 4-8 on #! Waldorf 64-bit?

Tags: debian, gcc, c++, crunchbang

I would like to install and use g++ 4-8 compiler. It supports various C++11 features, and I am willing to look into them and use them. Also, as I came here from Windows, my previous files also used C++11.

I looked for a moment and found [this site.](http://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/gcc-4.8-base/download) It contains .deb package with 4-8 gcc base. I downloaded it and installed, but synaptic shows that it isn't supported. Is there a way I can use it?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `synaptic shows that it isn't supported`? What error message do you get? How did you try and install the package?

Comment: Of course. I installed it using synaptic manager(I suppose; r-clicked on .deb file). It installed just fine, but gcc-base 4.7 still sits in my packages(synaptic shows it's installed). There are some icons in GUI, and the one that base 4.8 lacks is "package is supported"(although I have other packages without support and running). However, if I try to compile, it doesn't work. Should I also install new g++ from some other source, or? Because with gcc 4-.7 base I have gcc 4-7. I don't have any gcc 4-8. Just base.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new info rather than placing it in the comments, it is hard to read and easy to miss. A screenshot might be helpful as well. Anyway, you should also install `gcc-4.8` which you will find on the debian packages page you linked to.

Comment: Thank you. There are a lot of dependencies, and my distro is based on Debian Wheezy(stable), yet these are from sid. Is there easier way to download these(with apt-get?), or do I have to download them one by one? I also hope that this won't destroy anything in my system...

Comment: This is risky. It _probably_ will be fine but you could run into problems and enter dependency hell. Since you only just moved to Linux, I would recommend simply using a newer distro, Debian testing for example. If that is not an option, you can always try and install the newer gcc, updating whatever it tells you to update.